# Can anyone help me with a BS to AD date converter for flutter?

Tags: flutter, date

I am looking to input my user birth date with in BS date format.
BS date is useful date format in nepal.

What I want is to store:

> 2078-10-09 (nepali date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use https://pub.dev/packages/nepali_utils flutter package for nepali date.

In your pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  nepali_utils: ^3.0.3
```

Then,

```
import 'package:nepali_utils/nepali_utils.dart';

//parse date 
NepaliDateTime gorkhaEarthQuake = NepaliDateTime.parse('2072-01-12T11:56:25');
print(gorkhaEarthQuake.year); // 2072

NepaliDateTime currentTime = NepaliDateTime.now();
print(currentTime.toIso8601String()); //2076-02-01T11:25:46.490980
print(gorkhaEarthQuake.mergeTime(10, 20, 30));
// 2072-01-12 10:20:30.000
```

Similarly, use this package for:

NepaliDateTime
DateConversion
NepaliDateFormat
NepaliNumberFormat
NepaliUnicode
NepaliMoment
many yet to come